# TinyMCE Stripped the allowfullscreen attribute In iframe?

Tags: tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

Hi have gone through documentation of TinyMCE but could not able to find why TinyMCE Stripped the allowfullscreen attribute In iframe ? When I insert and re-edit it stripped .
Tried iframe URL

```
<iframe src="http://players.brightcove.net/4338955589001/Bkh63tBcx_default/index.html?videoId=5347595845001" width="320" height="240" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Live Fiddle  [code](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/8Lfaab). Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `valid_elements` attribute to tell TinyMCE what valid elements and attributes are allowed in the editor.

I updated [your fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/8Lfaab/1) with the following configuration line:

```js
valid_elements: "*[*]"
```

Admittedly you likely don't want to include all tags and all attributes but this shows that you can get this working.

Please note that your Fiddle is using TinyMCE 3.5.x - that version of TinyMCE is no longer under development.  It would be a really good idea to move to TinyMCE 4.5 which is the current release and under active development.  If you use TinyMCE 4.5 you can use `extended_valid_elements` as opposed to `valid_elements`.

Comment: Can you check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896117/tinymce-rupess-symbol-comes-as-rectangular-box .