# TinyMCE Rupess Symbol Comes as Rectangular Box

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-3

I have Added a new option in TinyMCE CharMap . but since font was not supporting in client system so how do we import custom font to Rupess symbol appear perfectly .

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add("charmap", function(e) {
function t() {
    return [
        ["8377", "Rupess Symbol"],
        ["160", "no-break space"],
         ..So on 
        ["8207", "right-to-left mark"]
    ]
 }
```

Please any one suggest or provide live fiddle with font supported and display Rupess Symbol . since we can't install font on client systems . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how you get a client machine to use a font you want to support a symbol?  Effectively you can't control what someone installs on their machine.

What you may be able to do is use inline styles to define the font family for the symbol to a font family that would work on most platforms?

Perhaps something like this:

```
<span style="font-family: 'Sans-Serif';">&#8377;</span>
```

In my brief testing this renders on Windows and Mac machines.

Comment: But the code what you have given we can use as dec plced in charmap . means we can only use `["8377", "Rupess Symbol"]`. how do we use your's given code inside charmap array .

Comment: I had tried with your's code also it still appear as rectangular box